# Working out network bandwidth with .NET

Tags: .net

I need some advice on how to measure some statistics with my FTP application. Basically, I have a threaded application that [FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) to several machines which could be local or remote. Some are on the company LAN (Ethernet 100 Mbit/s) and others are contactable via [ADSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_digital_subscriber_line) lines (max bandwidth 1.5 Mbit/s).

What I would like to do is knowing which machines would take a long time to send data to (that is, the ADSL lines) and then delay transferring to them until other FTP transfers have finished.

Comment: How does your code do the actual connection?  If you're using a low level component, you basically need a timer when you start uploading/downloading and the total amount you've uploaded/downloaded.  You should be able to find standard formulas for bandwidth.  What matters more is how hard or easy it is for you to obtain these numbers from your code if you're using some higher level component.

Comment: We are using Rebex ftp components, so I'll have a look thanks. Are there any other network issues/stats I can use?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is sending data and measuring how long it takes. It may not be possible to send test data in your case. So you'll have to measure, and remember per host what the transmission speed is. You can try to predict based on the IP adress range.

Comment: IP Address range prediction? How does that work? We could send test data as long a it gets deleted on the machines (we wrote a custom ftp server so that would not be a problem).

Comment: Not too finegrained I'm afraid. The first distinction is that you can see if you're on the same subnet. That means your're on the same LAN. For other IP adresses, you can check if you talked to another computer from the same range, and assume the connection speed will be similar.

Comment: Thanks jdv. Any other stats you can think off that might help. I need to work out some sort of algorithm.